# How disable tsconfig.json autogeneration?

Tags: typescript, next.js, bit.dev

I have bit.dev component in my node modules which is written in typescript. And I need to remove node modules in tsconfig exclude array

Comment: more details please

Comment: Next js doesn't compile typescript in node modules. When I import my bit.dev package in react typescript project where node modules aren't excluded in tsconfig it works, but nextjs overrides tsconfig and error is thrown